# AutoCompleteTextView drop down height limited in dialog popup

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

The dialog pop-up is located [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYzNU.png).

How the AutoComplete results stop at the end of the pop-up view is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXh4K.png).

I want the results to drop down past the dialog's view to the parent view. If I can't do that then I want to limit the number of results the AutoComplete gives me to two.

This is in my on click listener for the popup menu.

```
addDialog.setContentView(R.layout.shoppinglistadd);

/**Capture the AutoCompleteTextView widget*/
final AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTV 
  = (AutoCompleteTextView) addDialog.findViewById(R.id.productEnteredShop);
/**Fills the autocomplete with possibilities*/
String[] acArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.completeFoodsList);
/**Create a new ArrayAdapter and bind shoppinglistitem.xml to each list item*/
ArrayAdapter<String> autoCompleteAdapter 
  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ShoppingList.this, R.layout.shoppinglistitem, acArray);
/**Associate the adapter with textView*/
autoCompleteTV.setAdapter(autoCompleteAdapter);
```

Answer (score 17):

You should use this method to limit the height of dropdown for `AutoCompleteTextView` widget in xml:

```
android:dropDownHeight="size"
```

Or use this to do programmatically

```
autoCompleteTextView.setDropDownHeight(int);
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 4):

For the limiting number of items part: you can override `getCount()` of `ArrayAdapter`:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
   return Math.min(2,super.getCount());
}
```

This works for filtering also.

Comment: I should've been more clear.  I'm not looking to limit the total results show to 2.  I'm looking to limit the maximum amount of results shown at a time to two with scrolling of the rest.

Comment: yep, this is not what he was asking. This just limits the result number.